# Converting lat/long (N7833 E01418)

Tags: coordinates, coordinate-systems, coordinate, coordinate-transformation, polar-coordinates

I have two coordinates that I want to convert to UTM and DMS, but I cant figure out which format they are in.

The coortinates: N7833  E01418

Does anyone know or are they bogus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates where in degrees and minutes.

N7833 = Hemisphere N, Degrees 78, Minutes 33

N01418 = Hemisphere N, Degrees 014, Minutes 18